# Error trying to use global variable from Bottlepy mounted app

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

I got a parent_app in a python file (parent.py) that I'm trying to mount in a child_app in another python file (child.py). The mount seems to work but, when I try to call a route from my parent_app trough the mount in my child_app, this route doesn't seems to be able to use global variable in my parent.py file.

The parent.py file:

```
from bottle import route
import bottle
import subprocess as sp

global extProc

parent_app = bottle.Bottle()

@parent_app.route('/start')
def start_bazarr():
    global extProc
    extProc = sp.Popen(['python','child.py'])

@parent_app.route('/stop')
def stop_bazarr():
    sp.Popen.terminate(extProc)

@parent_app.route('/restart')
def restart_bazarr():
    stop_bazarr()
    start_bazarr()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_bazarr()
```

The child.py file:

```
from bottle import route, run
import bottle
from parent import parent_app

child_app = bottle.Bottle()

@child_app.route('/')
def root():
    return u'Lorem Ipsum'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child_app.mount('/power', parent_app)
    child_app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

The URL I'm trying to call:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/power/restart
```

The error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
File "C:\Users\morpheus\Desktop\parent.py", line 20, in restart_bazarr
    stop_bazarr()
File "C:\Users\morpheus\Desktop\parent.py", line 16, in stop_bazarr
    sp.Popen.terminate(extProc)
NameError: global name 'extProc' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the global scope, you don't need the `global` keyword. You can define it , and set it to `None` as a temporary placeholder.

```
from bottle import route
import bottle
import subprocess as sp

extProc = None
```

And the `terminate` function needs to know about the use of `extProc`

```
@parent_app.route('/stop')
def stop_bazarr():
    global extProc
    sp.Popen.terminate(extProc)
```

Comment: Now getting this: TypeError: unbound method terminate() must be called with Popen instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: That seems to be a matter of how you're calling `terminate`. If you're getting an unbound error, you need to pass an instance of that class as the first parameter as the first argument for `terminate`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the start_bazarr() function definition, no? And I call start_bazarr() in the main so extProc should be set.

Comment: Thanks but definitely not solving the case.

Comment: Is it terminating at this line `extProc = sp.Popen(['python','child.py'])`?

Comment: It didn’t throw an error, it just don’t terminate the process. I’m using it on Windows 10 with python 2.7.